# sample variance always greater than 0 with probability 1

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, normal-distribution

Consider i.i.d random variables $X_1,..,X_n$, where $X_i$ is normal with $N(m,v)$.
The sample variance is given by: $V :=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n (X_k-\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)^2$
Why is it the case, that $V>0$ with probability 1. Therefore it hast to hold:

$P(\bigcap_{k=1}^n\{ X_k = M\} ) =0$

How can I evaluate that, since I have two random variables involved?

Comment: The expression you wrote for the variance is incorrect - it should involve a square, at the very least.

Comment: @user6247850: Yes I edited that.

Comment: That wasn't the only problem - it should also be the sample mean inside of the sum rather than just the sum of all the $X_i$s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample variance is zero if and only if all the samples are the same.  In particular, the variance is non-zero if $X_1 \ne X_2$, so $\mathbb{P}(V>0) \ge \mathbb{P}(X_1\ne X_2) = 1$.

Comment: The question is how do I evaluate the probability of two random variables: $$P(X_ 1 =X_2 )= P(X_1-X_2 =0) = 0$$ since the difference is normal, too.

Comment: Yes, $X_1-X_2$ is normal.  What is the probability of a normally distributed random variable equaling any specific value?  Or, if $Y$ is a normal random variable, you could think about it as $P(Y\ne 0)=P(Y>0)+P(Y<0)$